# Accessing and editing firefox saved form data from Web Extension API

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to access and edit saved form data like usernames, passwords, addresses, etc using the new Web Extension API in Firefox (and later on also in Google Chrome-based browsers). I cannot seem to find accurate and current information on this topic.

Is there a simple way to access stored form data in Mozilla Firefox using the Web Extension API and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for (general) saved form data; for usernames and passwords there is the logins API which is in development (not yet available), see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1324919

I opened a feature request to add a "autofill" API to WebExtensions. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1436178

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was hoping I was just missing something.